# CSVファイルを読み込んでデータを処理する時のエラーについて

Tags: python, python3, pandas, csv

CSVファイルをpandasで読み込んでリストの作成と平均のまとめを行った結果、エラーになってしまい、ファイルに原因があるのか、コードに原因があるのかが分かりません。
解決策があればご意見、よろしくお願いします。

**コード**

```
import pandas as pd

# pandasでcsvを読み込む
df = pd.read_csv("kion10y.csv", encoding="utf-8")

# 日付ごとに気温をリストにまとめる
md = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    m,  d,v = (int(row['月']), int(row['日']), float(row['気温']))
    key = str(m) + "/" + str(d)
    if not(key in md): md[key] = []
    md[key] += [v]

# 日付ごとに平均を求める
avs = {}
for key in md:
    v = avs[key] = sum(md[key]) / len(md[key])
    print("{0} : {1}".format(key,v))
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fujiokamasaya/Desktop/python.test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4411, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 44, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 45, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas/_libs/util.pxd", line 98, in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at
  File "pandas/_libs/util.pxd", line 83, in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fujiokamasaya/PycharmProjects/project/tenki.1.py", line 10, in <module>
    m,  d,v = (int(row['月']), int(row['日']), float(row['気温']))
  File "/Users/fujiokamasaya/Desktop/python.test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/fujiokamasaya/Desktop/python.test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4419, in get_value
    raise e1
  File "/Users/fujiokamasaya/Desktop/python.test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: '月'
```

**CSVファイルの内容**

```
年, 月, 日, 気温, 品質, 均質, 
2010,1,5,7.4,8,1
2010,1,6,4.6,8,1
2010,1,7,4.5,8,1
2010,1,8,5.5,8,1
2010,1,9,5.8,8,1
2010,1,10,7.3,8,1
2010,1,11,7.0,8,1
2010,1,12,6.8,8,1
2010,1,13,2.5,8,1
2010,1,14,2.3,8,1
2010,1,15,4.6,8,1
2010,1,16,3.9,8,1
2010,1,17,3.9,8,1
2010,1,18,5.4,8,1
2010,1,19,7.9,8,1
2010,1,20,9.9,8,1
2010,1,21,10.3,8,1
2010,1,22,6.5,8,1
```

Comment: CSVファイルもエラーの可能性として考えられるのであれば、実際に使用しているデータを質問文に含めておくと回答が得られやすくなると思います。

Comment: dfをprintで出力した結果が、以下になります。

         年   月   日   気温   品質   均質    
0     2010   1   5  7.4    8    1 NaN
1     2010   1   6  4.6    8    1 NaN
2     2010   1   7  4.5    8    1 NaN
3     2010   1   8  5.5    8    1 NaN
4     2010   1   9  5.8    8    1 NaN
...    ...  ..  ..  ...  ...  ...  ..
3644  2019  12  28  7.3    8    1 NaN
3645  2019  12  29  8.4    8    1 NaN
3646  2019  12  30  9.7    8    1 NaN
3647  2019  12  31  9.5    8    1 NaN
3648  2020   1   1  6.9    8    1 NaN

[3649 rows x 7 columns]

プロセスは終了コード 0 で完了しました

Comment: CSVファイルを読み込む際に `skipinitialspace=True` を指定するとよろしいかと思います。, `df = pd.read_csv("kion10y.csv", encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)`

Comment: ちなみにですが、平均気温は `df.groupby(['年', '月', '日'])['気温'].mean()` としても求める事が可能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

ファイルに原因があるのではないかと予想されます。
csvに`月`カラムがあるかご確認ください。

@metropolis さんのコメントの通り、csvのヘッダにスペースが入っているのが原因のようです。
[公式ドキュメント(英語)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)や[解説ブログ](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)を参考に`skipinitialspace`を有効にしてください。

うまく行くcsv

```
月,日,気温
1,2,3
1,2,6
# 1/2 : 4.5
```

同様のエラーになるcsvその1

```
すっぽん,日,気温
1,2,3
1,2,6
```

同様のエラーになるcsvその2

```
 月, 日, 気温
1,2,3
1,2,6
```

検証コード

```
import pandas as pd

# エラーになる
#df = pd.read_csv("kion10y.csv", encoding="utf-8")
# エラーにならない
df = pd.read_csv("kion10y.csv", encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)

md = {}
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    m, d,v = (int(row['月']), int(row['日']), float(row['気温']))
    key = str(m) + "/" + str(d)
    if not(key in md):
       md[key] = []
    md[key] += [v]

avs = {}
for key in md:
    v = avs[key] = sum(md[key]) / len(md[key])
    print("{0} : {1}".format(key,v))
```

Comment: ファイル内容です。

年, 月, 日, 気温, 品質, 均質, 
2010,1,5,7.4,8,1
2010,1,6,4.6,8,1
2010,1,7,4.5,8,1
2010,1,8,5.5,8,1
2010,1,9,5.8,8,1
2010,1,10,7.3,8,1
2010,1,11,7.0,8,1
2010,1,12,6.8,8,1
2010,1,13,2.5,8,1
2010,1,14,2.3,8,1
2010,1,15,4.6,8,1
2010,1,16,3.9,8,1
2010,1,17,3.9,8,1
2010,1,18,5.4,8,1
2010,1,19,7.9,8,1
2010,1,20,9.9,8,1
2010,1,21,10.3,8,1
2010,1,22,6.5,8,1

Comment: 検証コードを実行した結果、同様にエラーになりました。

Comment: コードと説明文を変更しました。再度ご確認ください。

Answer (score 0):

ヘッダの月から均質まで、前にスペースが入ってます。

```
年, 月, 日, 気温, 品質, 均質,
```

スペースを削除してみてください。

```
年,月,日,気温,品質,均質,
```

Comment: スペースが入っている事に気付きませんでした。。。スペースを削除して再実行したら無事、完了しました！！ありがとうございます！！